# WPF RoutedEvents Being Handled By...?

Tags: wpf, 3d, routed-events

I have a 3D application in WPF which basically is supposed to zoom in and out as the MouseWheel event is fired. I have attempted to subscribe everything possible, but can't find what it is which is handling it.

Is there a way to find out what is? Or is there a way to have the event not handled, or for an encompassing UIElement to get to this event before/after the one dealing with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get called even though someone else has already handled the event, try subscribing to the event using the `UIElement.AddHandled(RoutedEvent, bool)` function. Pass in `true` as the second argument to get called even if the event has been handled.

You can also try subscribing to the `PreviewMouseWheel` event to get called when the event is [tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies).